# Nasa turbofan dataset: Test and train dataset at different sample sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've tried to trian a model but I faced an error. Here is my code

```
Train1 = train1.astype('float32')         
test1 = test1.astype('float32')
train1 /= 255.0              
test1 /= 255.0

Xtrain = np.concatenate([train1, test1])
X_train, X_test= train_test_split(Xtrain,test_size=0.3)

print(test1)
                     
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units =100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape = (1,X_train.shape[1])))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(units =50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')) # Prediction of the next value
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, X_test, epochs=10, batch_size=200, verbose=1)`
```

I take error:

```
Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 23608
  y sizes: 10119
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

X_train = (26,23608)
X_test = (26,10119)
```

I need to prepare my train and test data set in a proper way. Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please explain what problem(s) you are facing? [Learn how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should tag this with whatever framework or library you are using as well. This is not a *language* error, but a semantic error produced by whatever framework/library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`model.fit()` takes x, y as first two arguments, while you are passing x_train and x_test (of different sizes).

x and y should have the same size since i-th x refers to i-th y. Usually `train_test_split` is used as

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3)`

Then you can train your model:

`history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=200, verbose=1)`

Finally you can evaluate the model performance by using evaluate:

`model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)`

I suggest you to read both [Keras](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) and [Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) documentation on these topics.

Comment: Did it answer your question?